# Can I do this using only spread and destructuring assignment?

Tags: javascript

From this array of objects, I would like to create an array of the values of `p`. ie. `['a', 'b']`.

Can I do this using only spread and destructuring assignment?

```
const arr = [ {p:'a'}, {p:'b'} ]

e.g.

console.log(...arr.p) // not valid syntax
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a reason you only wish to use "spread and destructuring assignment" here?

Comment: Because it would be cooler.

Comment: Too bad there is no spread \de-restructure syntax to do this without map.  I was looking for a practical use of this and after trying  a lot, discovered this question was already asked but no strong reason of why . Probably ECMA adds such syntax someday.   I already can do use detructure as follows to get individual values from any position of the array. Not sure why not to extend the syntax to be able to do this for each value: 
let [{["p"]:p1}] = [...arr];
let [,{["p"]:p2}] = [...arr];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not a use case for spread syntax. You should use the [`map` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
console.log(arr.map(o => o.p))
```

You can use destructuring in the parameter declaration to access the property, but it won't increase readability:

```
console.log(arr.map(({p}) => p))
```

Answer (score 1):

The spread operator is the wrong thing to use in that case.

You should use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead.

```js
const secondArr = arr.map((object) => object.p);
console.log(secondArr);
```